# How to create a template based on this work? (screenshots included)

Tags: templates

I know this is a very general question but I reach a point in which I need help. I need to replicate this

[image]
By now I managed to do this

[image]

but as you may notice:

- Space between line in title is too big
- Block below title (A, Via, De, Fecha y Referencia) needs formatting.

The rest of the text is quite similar :)

This 'template' is based on the work form [Rob Oakes](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/memo) and after downloading it I modified the **cls** file adding new variables. Please check out the original template or download my [modified template](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-DGTaH6UKTToJaJ1Q_1zvxBf7YzqwwXq).

I need help to format the list above. Any advice?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! 
1) use `\\[-7pt]` or simmilar for reducing the space of the line seperators (in the title)
2) Use a tabular for the blocks below title and a tabular inside that tabular manually broken in lines (or a p{} column or a minipage) for the broken line of "Referencia"

Comment: This was useful. Number 1 did it. For number 2 I'm quite confused, could you refer me to anything similar to what you proposed? I'm going to look in deep for that.

Comment: you could just add a `\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}l}{\bfseries A:}&James Smith\\{\bfseries Via:}& Something \\ ... \\ Referencia &\begin{tabular}{l}A big text here that we will break manually with this \\ and continue to next line\end{tabular}\\\end{tabular}` under the title

Comment: Ah! it helped very much but `\end{minipage}` is missing. In order to keep things easy to replicate I'm thinking to avoid the use of templates and do a nice tex file instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at last you can start with a simple `article` document, you do not need a complete template for that.

A simple starting point for you can be the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}  % <============================= \includegraphics
\usepackage{showframe} % <============ visualize typing area and margins
\usepackage{lipsum}    % <=================================== dummy text

\usepackage[scaled]{helvet} % <===================== or libertine or ...
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} % <=== Sans serif to be standard!


\begin{document}

\noindent\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-duck} \hfill \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}

\begin{center}
{\Huge Title}\\
{\Large second line}\\
third line
\end{center}

\vspace{2\baselineskip}

\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{8cm}}
  {\bfseries A:}         & James Smith\\
  {\bfseries Via:}       & Something \\ 
  ... \\ 
  {\bfseries Referencia} & A big text here that we will break manually with this and continue to next line\\%
\end{tabular}

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
Senior Director
\vspace{2\baselineskip}

\lipsum[1]

\section{INTRODUCTION}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

It gives you the result:

[image: resulting pdf]

It seems you want to rebuild a formula for your company/institute. Because I do not know the specifications that is left for you (for example the distance between title and second title line). With package `geometry` you can define the margins you need etc.

But for a starting point it is good enouph I think.

Comment: Actually, I realized my work was a bit much. This suggestion is very helpful and I´ll do it.